# pgf-umlsd rectangles and text

Tags: pgf-umlsd

I have several issues with this package to draw my sequence diagram:
How can it is possible position correctly the rectangle according to the position of the other elements? For example I defined the Client A and I would to put the rectangle under it. Further, between the message exchange, I have other rectangles to depict (A side and B side) with a lot of text to put inside. I tried to use the newline but it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{sequencediagram}
    \tikzstyle{inststyle}+=[bottom color=white, top color=white, rounded corners=3mm]
    \newinst[0]{a}{Client A}
    \newinst[5]{b}{Server B}
    \node [draw] (s) at (a) {$k_i, k_r, k_1, k_2 = \textsf{kdf}(g^{x,y},n_i|n_r)$};
    \begin{call}{a}{$[k_i, k_r, k_1, k_2k_i, k_r, k_1, k_2,k_i, k_r, k_1, k_2],aa$}{b}{$[k_i, k_r, k_1, k_2k_i, k_r, k_1, k_2k_i,  k_r, k_1, k_2]$}
    \end{call}
    \end{sequencediagram}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What I would to have:

[image]

Comment: The picture of what you would like to have looks rather different from your current output, what is the relation between the k_x sequences and all the test nodes?

Comment: It is an example. The second figure is the skeleton that I would to have. the text that you see in the figure 1 is an example. Further, "test" is text inside the rectangle. They are not nodes.